# I have somehow broken my Rails app - the dreaded NoMethod Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

The error message is `NoMethodError in Circuit#update` `undefined method 'network_address' for nil:NilClass` and related to this line in my view:

```
<td><%= logical_interface.subnet.network_address %></td>
```

Everything was working perfectly earlier and now I've managed to break it somehow when I restarted my local server.

**update.rhtml**

```
<table id="logical_interfaces">
    <% @logical_interfaces.each do |logical_interface| %>
        <tr id="logical_interface_<%= logical_interface.id %>">
            <td><%= logical_interface.description %></td>
            <td><%= logical_interface.subnet.network_address %></td>
            <td><%= logical_interface.bandwidth %></td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

**logical_interface.rb**

```
belongs_to :subnet
belongs_to :circuit
```

**subnet.rb**

```
belongs_to :logical_interface
belongs_to :circuit
```

**circuit.rb**

```
has_many :subnets
has_many :logical_interfaces
```

**circuit_controller.rb**

The CRUD is being done inside the controller of another model because this is the main object which everything else runs off.

```
def update

  ....
  if params[:id]
    @circuit = Circuit.find(params[:id])
  end

  @logical_interfaces = LogicalInterface.find_all_by_circuit_id(@circuit.id)
  ....

end
```

As is common with bugs, I'll bet this is something silly but I genuinely can't work it out for myself so would greatly appreciate any answers. I have a feeling it's to do with the relationships that have been defined between the models but I could be wrong.

Comment: One of your records `logical_interface` has not subnet associated to it, so when call `logical_interface.subnet.network_address`, it raises "Nil does not have a 'network_address' method" => use `logical_interface.subnet.try(:network_address)` to see which of the record is corrupted and add validates presence on the Subnet model if subnet should be mandatory for a logical_interface.

Comment: `logical_interface.subnet` is nil, probably because that record doesn't have a subnet associated with it. You get that error because you're trying to call a method on a nil object, and the Nil object doesn't have that method.

Comment: thanks, will try to dig a little further, I must have deleted something from the db....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subnet` is `nil` for `logical_interface`. Either add some validation in `LogicalInterface` model:

```
validates_presence_of :subnet
```

or display `network_address` only if `subnet` is present.

```
<td><%= logical_interface.subnet.try(:network_address) %></td>
```

Comment: thanks, this allowed me to get the page to render and see that the subnet was indeed empty but not sure how it actually got like that.